# Which Eclipse should I download in order to start Android Apps Development?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm lost in this list : 
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

I downloaded the first one : 
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, 221 MB

I saw the comparison table but I want your experience guys, which one should I download?

Comment: I think you can download any one, after that just install the ADT plugin.

Comment: If you haven't used Eclipse before then you might want to try [InteliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) instead. It is a very competent IDE and has superb [Android](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_android.html) support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will only need Eclipse IDE for JAVA Developer. EE plugin is not required by any mean for android development. It is just of 149 MB of size. Once you have Eclipse just for JAVA development, you can go ahead with installing the adt plugin on it.

Comment: Agreed, with the one exception that if the app is to act as a client to a server-side app then Java EE support would be nice to have in the same IDE.

Comment: No, if your app is making a call to server side, you need not to have EE plugin, it can be done by just making http calls. You might need EE plugin only when you are developing server side code along with that.

Comment: I didn't say you had to have it, I said it would be nice to have it in the same IDE.

Comment: yes if you are developing both its indeed must to have feature.

Comment: Thank you , i'll just keep the one including EE plugin for future use hopefully :)

Answer (score 2):

**-** Download the `Eclipse Indigo Classic` version.

**-** Install the `ADT plugin` into it.

**-** Then Install the `Android SDK`.

Comment: just for curiousity, can you tell me what's the difference between the ADT PLugin and Android SDK ?

Comment: @AlanDeep  Here it is....   The `Android SDK` separates tools, platforms, and other components into packages, then it includes debugger, libraries,etc.. Now Android offers a custom plugin for the Eclipse IDE, called `Android Development Tools (ADT)`. This plugin is designed to give you a powerful, integrated environment in which to develop Android apps